# Angular 5: rearrange dynamically created components

Tags: angular

I use the `ComponentFactoryResolver` to create components dynamically as [shown in the docs](https://angular.io/guide/dynamic-component-loader).

```
// create a component each time this code is run
public buildComponent() {
  const factory = this.componentFactoryResolver.resolveComponentFactory(MyComponent);
  const componentRef = this.viewContainerRef.createComponent(factory);
  const component = componentRef.instance;

  this.componentArray.push(component);
}
```

This works well. Each time the function runs a new `MyComponent` is created and added to the DOM at the provided `ViewContainerRef` location. Now following some user action, I'd like to reorder the components. For instance I may want to move the last created component up one spot in the container. Can this be done within Angular?

```
public moveComponentUp(component) {
  // What to do here?  The method could also be passed the componentRef
}
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You could have method like:

```typescript
move(shift: number, componentRef: ComponentRef<any>) {
  const currentIndex = this.vcRef.indexOf(componentRef.hostView);
  const len = this.vcRef.length;

  let destinationIndex = currentIndex + shift;
  if (destinationIndex === len) {
    destinationIndex = 0;
  }
  if (destinationIndex === -1) {
    destinationIndex = len - 1;
  }

  this.vcRef.move(componentRef.hostView, destinationIndex);
}
```

that will move component depending on `shift` value:

```typescript
move(1, componentRef) - up
move(-1, componentRef) - down
```

**[Stackblitz example](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-wxnsjh?file=styles.css)**

Comment: what is the shift value exactly is? is it the index number of componentRef in vcRef to which we want to move. i.e. I want 0 index componentRef to 1 index thus the 0-index componentRef will be shifted at index 1 and 1 will be shift value that I need to provide? right!!!